Cómo Traducir al español el componente CALENDAR de PRIMENG en Angular 18
Cómo Traducir al español el componente CALENDAR de PRIMENG en Angular 18
Estoy utilizando la opción Standalone=true, no utilizo el app.Module.ts, y nada me funciona.
Ya se me agotan las ideas, todas las opciones anteriores no funcionan.

¿Qué opciones has probado?

Como puedes ver en el repositorio oficial, primeng aún NO soporta los componentes standalone.
Así que suponiendo que vuelves a agregar los componentes por módulos, y en base a su documentación

descarga la traducción del idioma que vayas a usar del repositorio primelocale


elimina la clave del idioma y deja solo el valor
{
"en":
    {
    ...
    }
}

Usa en su lugar:
{
...
}


implementa la traducción para usar ng-translate
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
 import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

 @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html'
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(private config: PrimeNGConfig, private translateService: TranslateService) {}

     ngOnInit() {
         this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
     }

     translate(lang: string) {
         this.translateService.use(lang);
         this.translateService.get('primeng').subscribe(res => this.config.setTranslation(res));
     }
 }




Muchas Gracias lo voy a intentar.
